# Método Para Receber Valores genéricos

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

Saudações.

Tenho um método que recebe 3 paramêntros: **coleção, negócios, quantidade**

**Coleção:** é uma classe *collection* que herda que uma outra classe, ex: homem, mulher, idoso...
**Negócios:** é uma classe que contém os métodos que fazem as tratativas antes de acessar o banco de dados(programação em 3 camadas).
**Quantidade:** é apenas um valor do tipo inteiro.

Agora imagine que a minha coleção pode ser:
homemCollection, mulherColection, idosoCollection ou criançaCollection.

Imagine que a minha classe negocios pode ser:
homemNegocios, MulherNegocios, IdosoNegocios, criancaNegocios...

O que eu pretendo é que meu método receba qualquer um destes valores e assim eu utilizarei ele para qualquer uma destas classes.

Eu pesquisei sobre métodos genéricos, classes genéricas, Linq, porém não consegui resolver o problema.

Segue o codigo do Método:

```
private void MeuMetodo(HomemCollection colecao, HomemNegocios negocios, int quantidade)
{
   string retorno = negocios.nomeDoMetodoDaCamadaNegocios(colecao, negocios, quantidade)
}
```

Este método acima só pode receber a coleção e a negócios de homem, quero deixar este método recebendo qualquer outra classe.

Caso alguém tenha algum link ou material para eu estudar essa situação, fico muito grato.

Comment: As classes `Collection` e `Negocios`, elas herdam de um tipo único, ou implementam alguma `interface`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome disso é justamente "[tipos genéricos](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)"

O método ficaria assim:

```
private void MeuMetodo<TCol, TNeg>(TCol colecao, TNeg negocios, int quantidade) { }
```

O uso seria assim:

```
MeuMetodo<HomemCollection, HomemNegocio>(collection, negocio, qtd);
```

Na verdade, como os parâmetros `colecao` e `negocios` são dos tipos genéricos, é possível esconder o tipo genérico e deixar que o compilador faça a inferência de tipo.

```
MeuMetodo(collection, negocio, qtd); 
// já que collection é do tipo HomemCollection
// e negocio é do tipo HomemNegocio
```

Perceba que para você conseguir chamar algum método de `negocio` vai precisar que este método esteja definido dentro do método genérico de alguma forma, isso se faz usando [*constraints* (restrições)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) de tipo. Por exemplo:

```
interface INegocio
{
    MetodoDaCamadaNegocios();
}

class MinhaClasse
{
    private void MeuMetodo<TCol, TNeg>(TCol colecao, TNeg negocios, int quantidade) where TCol : INegocio
    {
        negocio.MetodoDaCamadaNegocios();
    }
}
```

A parte **`where TCol : INegocio`** obriga que o tipo genérico `TCol` seja uma implementação de **`INegocio`**. Assim, o compilador pode ter certeza de quais são os métodos existentes em `TCol`.

Comment: Depois eu tento melhorar a resposta, explicar melhor e cobrir outros casos.

Comment: obrigado por sua resposta, Fiz da forma que você mencionou, criei uma interface e coloquei o método da negócios dentro desta interface, funcionou ok... Minha dúvida é : A unica forma de chamar estes métodos é passando eles para a interface?

Comment: @Agnaldo Sim, porque o compilador precisa saber que o método existe de antemão. Aliás, não sei se você sabe, mas você pode escolher uma resposta para suas perguntas (apenas uma), é só marcar o **V** do lado esquerdo da resposta.

Comment: Obrigado. Achei que dava para marcar as duas. hehe

Answer (score 1):

Agnaldo exitem várias maneiras de fazer isso. Em uma delas você pode criar uma interface e fazer todas as suas collections implementa-las, por exemplo `IMinhaInterface`

```
public interface IMinhaInterface {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    /// outras properties
}
```

Classes :

```
public class HomemCollection : IMinhaInterface {
    /// propriedades unicas desta collection
}

public class MulherCollection : IMinhaInterface {
    /// propriedades unicas desta collection
}

public class CriancaCollection : IMinhaInterface {
    /// propriedades unicas desta collection
}
```

Aí seu método ficaria:

```
private void MeuMetodo(IMinhaInterface colecao, HomemNegocios negocios, int quantidade)
{
   string retorno = negocios.nomeDoMetodoDaCamadaNegocios(colecao, negocios, quantidade)
}
```

O mesmo se aplica aos outros casos mencionados. Isso se chama [polimorfismo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism).

Comment: É um pouco mais complexo, você poderia apresentar a implementação mais completa?

Comment: @Fabri Damazio, Obrigado pela resposta, irei estudar sobre polimorfismo. Em sua resposta eu fiquei com uma dúvida e por esse motivo não consegui ainda implementar. A minha Classe HomemCollection já herda da classe Homem. Como Faço para ela herdar da classe homem e também da interface?

Comment: @Agnaldo ela não herda da interface e sim implenta a interface. No caso ficaria HomemCollection : Homem, IMinhaInterface

Comment: @Fabri Damazio - Entendi, muito obrigado pela paciência e explicações.